# Set null if combobox selected index = 0

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a simple model like this:

```
 public class NoteModel
    {
        public Guid? DesignGroupId { get; set; }
        public int? ProjectKey { get; set; }
        public int? DesignKey { get; set; }
    }
```

So I want to set model like:

```
 NoteModel model = new NoteModel();
```

That properties depending of selected combobox selected value so I need to do:

```
 if(cboDesignGroup.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
                model.DesignGroupId = Guid.Parse(cboDesignGroup.SelectedValue.ToString());
            }
```

So every property have a if clause depending of his dropdown. If combobox = 0 then is just null because I never set it.

Is there another way to do this more clean and readeable? Regards

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET......?

Comment: there are total of 3 comboboxes based on 3 properties in the model?

Comment: Do you know that if you select the first item in a combo box, then the selected index is 0.  If nothing is selected, it's `-1`.

Comment: Yes, I know, thats why I have a default option in combobox which if is set I want null @Flydog57

Comment: if `If condition` bothering you, you could use `ternary operator` to do it in a single line of code as: `model.DesignGroupId = cboDesignGroup.SelectedIndex != 0 ? Guid.Parse(cboDesignGroup.SelectedValue.ToString()) : null;`

Comment: Yes, 3 comboboxes based on that 3 properties @RashidAli

Comment: WinForms @Steve

Comment: I tryied it but it throws error `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'Guid' and '<null>'` @RashidAli

Comment: Try changing `: null` to `: (Guid?)null`.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel it wont work i think, `default(Guid)` would work as default value to Guid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make some efforts to populate your list box nicely it will make the code elsewhere nicer. This example uses c# 7 ValueTuple but you could use Tuple, or make your own class with just a string and Guid? Property

```
var items = new List<(string, Guid?)>();
items.Add(("No selection", (Guid?)null));
items.Add(("Option 1", (Guid?)Guid.NewGuid()));
items.Add(("Option 1", (Guid?)Guid.NewGuid()));
```

ValueTuple declared as above has a property `.Item1` that is a string (for display in the combo) and an `.Item2` that is a `Nullable<Guid>` (for insert to the model). You get the items into your combo by binding:

```
yourcombo.DataSource = items;
yourcombo.DisplayMember = "Item1"; //string name of property to call to get display text -> the ValueTuple.Item1
yourcombo.DisplayMember = "Item2"; //name of property to use as value
```

Then after your user has made a selection (including No selection, the first item in the list) just assign the `comboBox.SelectedValue` to the model:

```
model.DesignGroupId = (Guid?)yourcombo.SelectedValue;
```

The combo doesn't have a "blank" state; that's why the first item is "(No selection)", and this has a value that is of type Guid? and a value of "null"; it can be assigned straight to your model just like any other Guid? that has a value

There is no "if selectedindex" etc here; populating your model is literally just a direct assignment of the SelectedValue of the combo, into the model. The only way you can get it cleaner than that would be to databind the model property to the combo, probably with something like:

```
yourcombo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", model, "DesignGroupId");
```

Then every time the combo loses focus it will poke the currently selected value into the `model.DesignGroupId`

:)

---

If you don't have c#7 then you can use Tuple:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var l = new List<Tuple<string, Guid?>>();
        l.Add(Tuple.Create("No sel", (Guid?)null));
        l.Add(Tuple.Create("opt 1", (Guid?)Guid.NewGuid()));
        l.Add(Tuple.Create("opt 2", (Guid?)Guid.NewGuid()));

        comboBox1.DataSource = l;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Item1";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Item2";

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        model.Whatever = (Guid?)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Or you can use your own class, though it's the sort of thing that Tuple was invented for, so you don't have umpteen little classes around the place that are nothing more than a pairing of a couple of primitives

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code suggest that if anything but the first element is selected in the combobox, the guid is set.

0 is actually a valid index, as a combobox is a zero bound index. (0 is the first element, 1 is the second and so on).

You you want to depend on the selectedIndex, you should write something like this:

```cs
if(cboDesignGroup.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
  model.DesignGroupId = Guid.Parse(cboDesignGroup.Items[cboDesignGroup.SelectedIndex].ToString());
}

//Depending of which framework you are using (WPF, WinForms etc), you could write something like this:

//WPF & WinForms:
if (cboDesignGroup.SelectedItem != null)
  model.DesignGroupId = Guid.Parse(cboDesignGroup.SelectedItem.ToString());


//Or you could do something like this:
m.DesignGroupId = (cboDesignGroup.SelectedItem == null ? null : (Guid?)Guid.Parse(cboDesignGroup.SelectedItem as string));
```